# django-admin.py startproject returns CommandError

Tags: django

I've just installed django and I'm having trouble creating a project.

Running `django-admin.py startproject test_project` returns:

```
CommandError: '/usr/local/mysql-5.6.13-osx10.7-x86_64/docs/test_project' already exists
```

I also looked in the path above and there is no `test_project` folder.

Anybody come across this one?

**EDIT**

I restarted the terminal and tried again. The error has disappears but it doesn't seem to be creating the `test_project` folder on my desktop.

Comment: I know django dislikes it when users name their apps/projects generic things like 'auth' or 'project' - you may want to name it something different and see if it works. If the command fails again, you have a problem with your django installation most likely. If you're really set on calling the project `test_project`, are you sure that's where you want to save your django project? That path looks like an installation file path.

Comment: I think the answer is changing directory.

Comment: Ok, so looks like its creating the projects in a different path to what I expected. Is there anyway this can be manually set?

Comment: In your terminal, you are going to want to `cd [insert path here]` - `cd` stands for `change directory` - put whatever path you want to start your project in :)

Comment: @gersande ahh ofcouse! Thannks.

Answer (score 0):

*You [seem to have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180488/django-admin-py-startproject-returns-commanderror#comment26638378_18180488) [found your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180488/django-admin-py-startproject-returns-commanderror#comment26638285_18180488) through [gersande's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2400347/gersande) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180488/django-admin-py-startproject-returns-commanderror#comment26638343_18180488) (update your question if you haven't with the new problem); so I'm just going to formalize it here:*

> I restarted the terminal and tried again. The error has disappears but it doesn't seem to be creating the test_project folder on my desktop.

I'm not sure why restarting the terminal helped (and it's probably a heisenbug), but I do notice an incongruence in your question: you've (seemingly, as the command isn't outputting any errors; but you could confirm by checking if running `echo $?` is 0 right after) created you new Django project directory in `/usr/local/mysql-5.6.13-osx10.7-x86_64/docs/`, but you seem to be looking for it on your Desktop (which is mapped to a different folder, probably `~/Desktop`.

Simply navigate to the above path in your file explorer, or run `cd <directory>` to view it in your terminal.